# Create and import into table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I import XML (after some checks) with a stored procedure. (SP)

I want to create a new table for each import, that SP works however when I pass the tables name into the below code I get error:

```
Must declare the table variable "@sTablename".
```

Tried:

Making @sTablename --> DECLARE @sTablename var(50)

It must of been asked before but searched SO/Google but probably with the wrong question?

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddNewDataToHoldingTable] 

@sUPRN varchar(510),
@sTablename varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
---------------------------------------
INSERT INTO @sTablename
(
[UPRN]
) 

VALUES 
(
@sUPRN
)
---------------------------------------
END
```

Comment: you are trying to use same variable `@sTablename` as your procedure input variable and as well as your table variable.try  the different variables for both.use the below code if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it may help you.

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAddNewDataToHoldingTable] 

@sUPRN varchar(510),
@sTablename varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN
---------------------------------------
DECLARE   @sTablename_  TABLE (UPRN  varchar(510)) 

INSERT INTO @sTablename_
(
[UPRN]
) 

VALUES 
(
@sUPRN
)
---------------------------------------
END
```

**Note:** in this ive declared '@sTablename_' as the table variable which is different from your procedure input variable

Comment: close thanks but the table already exists, I actually have alot more inserts than one so can I drop the TABLE (UPRN  varchar(510))  ? Maybe something like DECLARE -atTablename_ 
SET -atTablename_ = atsTablename  (had to replace the at symbols)

Comment: @indofraiser where you have declared your table variable in your query..?

Comment: So early on I create a new table, lets say TableYYYMMDD then I want to import a bunch of data into this table. To do this I need to know the table to insert it into.